# XML File Extraction - relative path doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, file, path, relative-path

Really tired to search, it's just flooded with these kind of problems. I am trying to:

```
InputStream inputStream =  DBconnection.class.getResourceAsStream("com.xxx.xxxxx.internal.props.xml");      
Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.loadFromXML(inputStream);
```

Throws me null pointer exception

File located under com\xxx\xxxxx\internal\props.xml
I've tried with dots, slashes, I did search, I tried to understand - http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html?page=2
, got completely confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try with "/com/xxx/xxxxx/internal/props.xml" instead. Or just "props.xml" if DBConnection resides in the same package as th xml file.